# What does IsNumeric do?

Tags: sql-server-2008

`ISNUMERIC` returns 1 when the input expression evaluates to a valid numeric data type; otherwise it returns 0 ([MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx)).

So why is the output of this query 1?

```
select ISNUMERIC('5d9')
```

Comment: Most interesting. 5a9 isn't but 5d9 is. Will be watching this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure bit taking a shot at it!! :-)

ISNUMERIC returns 1 when the input expression evaluates to a valid integer, floating point number, money or decimal type

I think that in this case, it is considering the "d" to stand for decimal and hence considering it to be a number.

I think 5e9 should be similar as well as "e" is also used mathematically to denote exponent..Dont have SQL here to try it out right now..but i think result of 5e9 should be 1 for the same reason

EDIT : Some more context [here](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.html) (result of some quick googling!!)

Comment: 5e9 is numeric. Good answer. +1

Comment: Hmm... select cast('5d9' as int) fails. What a mess.

Answer (score 1):

```
select cast('5d9' as float)
```

Returns

```
5000000000
```

`d` appears to work in the same manner as `e`

Answer (score 1):

`ISNUMERIC()` has no practical use and should generally be avoided.

It tells you if a string can be converted to a numeric data type but, as you saw, that can include seemingly random characters. eg. it can also include +, -, $, etc.

(obviously, they're not random, but if you're using `ISNUMERIC()` for validation, you'll struggle to find a case where you want to allow all possibilities it allows)

Answer (score 0):

Hexa : 5d9  <==> Decimal : 1497

Comment: 5a9 isn't, so this falls down.

Comment: @spender: yeap, the first thing I tried when I saw the question was `5f9` with no luck. `5e9` works though... `e` is probably exponential notation but `d`?

Answer (score 0):

You will need some additional testing to make a better test. Consider using the Case statement.

```
declare @var varchar(32)

select @var = '42e2'

select @var AS InputValue,
       ISNUMERIC( @var ) AS TestResult,
       Case ISNUMERIC( @var )
         When 1
          Then CONVERT( float, @var )
         Else
           0
       End AS SimpleConversion,
       Case ISNUMERIC( @var )
         When 1
           Then
             Case
               When CONVERT( varchar(32), CONVERT( float, @var ) ) = @var
                 Then CONVERT( float, @var )
               Else
                 0
             End
         Else
           0
       End AS IntegerResult


InputValue                       TestResult  SimpleConversion       IntegerResult
-------------------------------- ----------- ---------------------- ----------------------
42e2                             1           4200                   0

(1 row(s) affected)
```